# Ignoring certain lines in a .txt file while randomly selecting a line

Tags: python

How can I ignore lines in a file containing certain characters like "Y"?

And what should I do to make it read a random line (lines without "Y") from the file?

The txt file should have this inside:

```
"Red Ribbon", "N"
"Big Bones", "Y"
"Green Dye", "Y"
"Tyrone Biggums", "N"
"Walmart-Guy-We-All-Hate", "Y"
"Trump", "N"
```

It should be able to randomly read one of the lines with the "N" whenever I run it

Comment: What is your code? What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this snippet.

```
import random

with open(<file_name>) as f:
    r = f.readlines()
    l = len(r)
    while True:
        c = random.randint(0, l-1)
        print(r[c].split(","))
        if r[c].split(",")[-1] != "Y":
            print(r[c])
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres an approach:

```
import random

with open("D:/sam.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file if line.rstrip().endswith(', "N"')]     #seperating those lines not containing Y

print(random.choice(lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have posted answers already, but here is a version which is more unpacked, which lets you understand the parts more easily.

```
import random

new_line_list = []
with open("stuff.txt") as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('stuff.txt')]
    for line in lines:
        if '\"N\"' in line:
            new_line_list.append(line)

print(random.choice(new_line_list))
```